# within each group-by, use formula for difference of values on the bottom row, picking column depending on whether one column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'sym': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
        'x': [100, 120, 80, 8, 8, 40],
        'y': [20, 20, np.nan, 20, np.nan, 20],
        'z': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    }
 )
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `out`:

```
  sym    x     y  z   out
0   a  100  20.0  2  17.0
1   a  120  20.0  3  17.0
2   b   80   NaN  4  76.0
3   c    8  20.0  5  13.0
4   c    8   NaN  6  13.0
5   c   40  20.0  7  13.0
```

Column `out` is created with this code:

```
def create_outcome(df):
    df['out'] = df.y.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
    return df

df = df.groupby('sym').apply(create_outcome)
```

And if the group has only one row and `y` is `nan`, `out` is `df['out'] = df.x.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]`. For example `b` in `sym` column is calculated like that.

When I change `create_outcome` to calculate `out` for `b` in `sym` column, It does not give me the above output. This is how I changed it:

```
def create_outcome(df):
    df['out'] = df.y.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
    mask = (
        (len(df) == 1) &
        (df.y.isna().all())
    )
    df.loc[mask, 'out'] = df.x.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
    return df
```

I also tried this:

```
df.loc[df.where(mask), 'out'] = df.x.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
```

I know that if I change my function with a conditional like:

```
if len(df) == 1 and df.y.isna().all():
    df['out'] = df.x.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
```

It works. But I wonder why it does not work when I use a mask.

Comment: What if a group has two rows and one y value is `nan`? Is that a possible scenario?

Comment: @Nick No. In my data the only case that all values in `y` are `nan` is when the group has only one row.

Comment: @Nick If a solution solves the problem for the example in my post, I can edit it according to my data. I just don't know why that mask doesn't work.

Comment: It's much clearer to state your question in words: **group-by 'sym', then within each group, use the (y-z) values from the bottom row, unless y is NaN, in which case (x-z) from the bottom row**

Comment: The question title is misleadingly broad (so it'll unwantedly show up in searches for other more common issues), and the premise "based on length of dataframe" is just wrong; it's really "Group dataframe, use (y-z) from bottom row of group unless y is NaN, else (x-z) from bottom row". @Amir can you edit it to be more specific and less broad?

Comment: @smci Is that what you suggest to be the title?
group-by 'sym', then within each group, use the (y-z) values from the bottom row, unless y is NaN, in which case (x-z) from the bottom row

Comment: That or anything similar that's ok by you, and less general, and omit the misleading *"based on length of dataframe"*.

Comment: Actually you haven't specified what it should output if a group has 2+ rows and y is NaN on the bottom row but non-NaN elsewhere in that group?

Comment: @smci Can you give me a suggestion that does not use column names? I can think about it. But I wanna know your suggestion. Something less specific maybe.

Comment: @smci My data does not have that kind of group. So I didn't think about all possible scenarios. The accepted answer has a solution for it. By using `fillna`

Comment: How about *"group-by 'sym', then within each group, use formula for difference of values from the bottom row, depending on whether one column y is NaN"*

Comment: @smci I'd probably be more inclined to describe the problem as something like `setting value using mask giving unexpected results in pandas` since the only actual question in the post is "But I wonder why it does not work when I use a mask." That's the question I answered...

Comment: @Nick Which one should i choose? Both of you have more expertise than me. I like yours more.

Comment: Let's see what @smci says...

Comment: Nick: the OP's question is not at all about "setting value using mask", that was only one of many possible implementations. That code was wrong (because they misused `isna().all()`, *not because the general concept of using a mask is bad*), there's nothing "unexpected" about it; that only illustrates the difference between `.any()` and `.all()`. Given any non-trivial problem in pandas, there could be tens to thousands of possible implementations, most of them (subtly) wrong. Wherever possible we should phrase a question with a clear positive intent, not get hung up on a wrong implementation.

Comment: Understanding the difference between `.any()` and `.all()` on a Python list or pandas Series is pretty basic and generic, and it doesn't make this a question about masks. (Just like say mistakenly attempting to find NaNs by comparing `== np.nan` is another very common mistake in masks, but again it doesn't make that about masks.)

Comment: @smci Actually I agree that "unexpected" is a little too much. I know that I must use a mask but that mask did not give me the result that I want. It was 'wrong' not 'unexpected.' I am not use to write titles that are too specefic. Maybe it is better to be more specific. I need to find out to what extent.

Comment: Ok here's another suggested phrasing: *"within each group-by, use formula for difference of values on the bottom row, picking column depending on whether one column is NaN"*. (I'm describing what we're trying to do, without specifying any particular implementation).

Comment: That's better. I wait a little bit more to hear from @NIck too. Or maybe a better suggestion will be found.

Comment: go for @smci suggestion, I'll go with the flow

Comment: Cool. I guess for the sake of completeness we should add in another group 'd' to test we get a sensible answer when group 'd' has 2+ rows and y is NaN on the bottom row but non-NaN elsewhere in that group.

Comment: @smci If I edit my question the primary solution is not relevant anymore because it has `len (df)== 1` but the secondary one that uses `fillna` will work. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your mask is a *single value* which acts as an index for the group (`False` => 0 for groups `a` and `c`, and `True` => 1 for group `b`). This is because you're using `df.y.isna().all()` What you actually want is to generate a *series* where that condition is true:

```py
def create_outcome(df):
    df['out'] = df.y.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
    mask = (
        (len(df) == 1) &
        (df.y.isna())
    )
    df.loc[mask, 'out'] = df.x.iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
    return df
```

Note that since `mask` can only be true when `len(df) == 1`, `df.y.isna()` is effectively the same as `df.y.isna().all()`.

Based on your sample data, you can simplify your code by just filling `nan` values in `y` with `x`:

```py
def create_outcome(df):
    df['out'] = df.y.fillna(df.x).iloc[-1] - df.z.iloc[-1]
    return df
```

Comment: I really like that `fillna`. Very smart :)

Comment: @Amir note that is based on your sample data; it will *only* work if the only way the last value of `y` will be `nan` is if there is only one row in the group.

Comment: Yeah I know. An answer usually is not correct for all possible scenarios. Really appreciate that. Thumbs up.

Comment: Although what would be the result for group `c` in your data if row `5` didn't exist?

Comment: In my data that kind of group does not exist.

Comment: In that case the `fillna` should work no problems.

Comment: Yes. It works that way too. I often use `fillna` columnwise. My eyes are not used to it the way you answer that.

Comment: Guys you really don't need to explicitly consider len() of each group. Just directly inspect whether the bottom y value in each group is NaN: `df.groupby('sym').apply(lambda g: g[['y']].iloc[-1].isnull())`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-line solution with no hackery about len() of a group:

```
df['out'] = df.groupby('sym').transform(lambda g: g.iloc[-1]).apply(lambda g: (g.x if pd.isna(g.y) else g.y) - g.z, axis=1)

>>> df

  sym    x     y  z   out
0   a  100  20.0  2  17.0
1   a  120  20.0  3  17.0
2   b   80   NaN  4  76.0
3   c    8  20.0  5  13.0
4   c    8   NaN  6  13.0
5   c   40  20.0  7  13.0
```

Some notes:

- `transform()` was the easiest way to get the bottom row of each group
- It's actually more grief to use the helpful-sounding `.last()` than `.transform(lambda g: g.iloc[-1])` because `.last()` doesn't broadcast the result to all rows in a group, so its indices aren't compatible for directly assigning back to parent dataframe
- then `apply(..., axis=1)` to implement the formula, involving multiple columns.

  - (The [`expr1 if cond else expr2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/202229) does not vectorize nicely in pandas. Could instead use `df.where()` to inspect for NAs and select column between 'x' and 'y', just the syntax is unwieldy).
- (Style tip: when writing a function like `create_outcome` or a lambda that operates on a groupby, it's better practice to name the argument `g` instead of `df`. This avoids shadowing the argument, makes it easier to debug, and calling the arg `g` makes it explicit that the function is (mainly/only) supposed to run on groups.)